# How to use Google Cloud SQL in progressive web app for offline database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, progressive-web-apps

How to make a offline website in Google Cloud SQL using progressive web app.How to synchronize Google Cloud SQL database to offline database. Can I use Google Cloud SQL in progressive web app for offline database?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL does not have any capability like this built in. There are some generic MySQL sync tools, but this wouldn't be able to enforce per-user security etc.

Probably the best bet is to use a database designed for this use-case, such as [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), which has [built-in offline sync for web apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline).

Answer (score 0):

Answering  your question, Google Cloud SQL doesn’ t allow an offline database. I recommend to take a look to  [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline)  which  supports offline data persistence and would be up to you if this may fit your use case.